# 403 Forbidden Error Posting PHP/HTML Form

Tags: php, html, forms, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have recently run into an issue where for some reason posting a html form immediately results in a "403 forbidden" error as soon as I click the submit button in my website. The web page loads perfectly fine before the submit button is clicked. My website is written in PHP and is running on an Amazon ec2 instance. Everything was working perfectly fine until all of a sudden I started getting this error. I had done extensive prior testing of this code and for some reason this only started happening now.

I have tried making a `.htaccess` file with the lines:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything (I did set `EnableOveride All` for my `/var/www` directory where my php files live).

I'm just not too sure where to go with this as the code was working perfectly fine with exactly the same form but now all of a sudden it no longer works. I even tried commenting out my php and just submitting the form with no logic to follow and still see this error so I don't think its a code issue but rather an apache/php issue on the server.

(I can't really post too much of my code cause its for an assignment)

Comment: What OS are you running on your EC2 instance? You may be running into issues with ModSecurity or something similar depending on your setup

Comment: @AaronMeese from my understanding the EC2 is running CentOS. I can't quite remember though. The Apache server is running as "https" and my package manager is Yum so I believe this is CentOS.

Comment: Are you URL encoding your request? I understand that you want to keep your code private but a little more context as to what your PHP looks like would help me try to pinpoint the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. I had an Amazon web application firewall that was blocking the posting of html forms. Disabling this allowed for the form to be posted as normal.